# Excel VBA Range object Error in Looping Through Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through different sheets in my workbook. I have tried searching through stackoverflow but still stuck with the error. The error showed "Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

The purpose of this code is to standardise all formats in the worksheets.

```
Sub formatting()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim lastRow as long, lastColumn as long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = (Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)

For each ws in Activeworkbook.Worksheets
With ws.Range(cells(lastRow, 1), cells(1, lastColumn))
    'rest of the actions I want to perform'
    .font.bold = true
End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

I just got started on Excel vba, please enlighten me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes to be made:
1. You have to redefine the last row and last column for each sheet. With that said, place the variable assignment inside the loop.

2. Instead of `ws.Range(cells...)`, the proper syntax is `Range(ws.cells...)`

See below:

```
Sub formatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long


    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn = (Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
        With Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
            'rest of the actions I want to perform'
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works!

I have some questions:
1) Why do you put the variable assignment inside the loop?
2) What's the difference with ws.Range(cells ...) & Range(ws.cells...)

Thank you so much! Just want to make sure I understand the code fully :)

Comment: No problem. What are the questions?

Comment: Can you read the questions above? I accidentally posted without finishing the question

Comment: Note it is better to use `ws.Range` not just `Range`. If the code is in a worksheet code module, it would raise an error otherwise.

Comment: 1. Variable assignment determines the last row and the last column of the worksheet. Unless each of the worksheets has exactly the same number of rows and same number of columns, you have to reassign it each time. Think about what is happening. The loop starts at sheet 1, checks the last row and last column, then performs the action. It loops to the next sheet. Should the same last row and column be used again, or should it be reassigned? 2. It's about properly qualifying objects. This will be more difficult to explain (and I'm running out of characters) so I will add another comment below.

Comment: 2 (cont). When the loop starts, it's on sheet 1 (for example). ws refers to sheet 1. Everything is fine. However, when it loops to the second sheet, Excel doesn't actually switch over to the second sheet. So, the active sheet is still sheet 1. Looking at the code, `ws` refers to sheet 2, so `ws.Range` expects a range object for sheet 2. However, since `Cells` is not qualified, Excel defaults to the active sheet (sheet 1). So the code basically says: `Sheet2.Range(Sheet1.Cells)...` Does that help to explain what's going on?

Comment: I got the process flow for Question 1. There are different rows and columns in each worksheet. For the code to properly determine the last row and column it will do a check at each loop. Am I right?

Comment: For question 2, what do you mean by "since 'cells' is not qualified?

Comment: @Rory thanks for the clarification! I will take note of it in worksheet code module.

Comment: One more question: Isn't `ws.cells(lastRow, lastColumn)` selecting the entire selection. Why do you need to reference it from the first cell?

Comment: 1. Correct, it will check last row/column in each worksheet. 2. By qualified, I mean its parent object is not selected. The parent being the worksheet within which the cells reside. Think of it like houses; each house has its own individual rooms, but they all belong to a different house (parent object). 3. It is not selecting the entire select. `Cells` refers to a SINGLE cell, at the `(ROW,COLUMN)`. When we write `RANGE(CELLS(1,1), CELLS(LR, LC))`, we select all of the cells in Range A1 : LASTROW/LASTCOLUMN

Comment: For 3) is LC referring to the last column cell on the first row or the last column cell at the last row? It maybe because I am misunderstanding this point. Thank you so much for helping me clarifying my doubts.

Comment: It's actually based on your definition. If you break down the code assigning a variable to LC into smaller parts, you can more easily understand it. First, `Cells(1, Columns.Count)` finds the very last Column on row 1. (In Excel 2010, that is Cell XFD1). Then, `End(xlToLeft)` finds the first column to the left of the last cell with data. If you have an irregular number of columns on different rows, LC would be different based on which row you select in the `CELLS` function. Of course, if you have contiguous data, you can use the `.CurrentRegion` property

Comment: Also, if you find that the solution has worked as needed, please mark the question as Answered to aid users who are performing searches in the future

Answer (score 0):

You have to qualify the `Cells` calls as well as the `Range` call:

```
With ws.Range(ws.cells(lastRow, 1), ws.cells(1, lastColumn))
```

Comment: This works as well! Thanks! Didn't know I have to add to add ws. to cells as well :)

Appreciate you taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you just got started in VBA I'd learn about setting ranges using .currentregion this will greatly help you in the future.

The code snippet makes all fields bold. If you are applying to all then currentregion can save code and possible errors on **one condition "that all the fields are connected."**

```
Sub formattingWithCurrentRegion()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Font.Bold = True
    Next ws

End Sub
```

By setting the area as a range you can get greater control over ranges to set different formatting without having to deal with loops in loops.
See below

```
Sub formattingWithCurrentRegion()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rSheet As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        '' sets the CurrentRegion as a range. Use the immediate window rSheet.Select to see what CurrentRegion does.
        Set rSheet = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        '' now you can work with it
        rSheet.Font.Bold = True

        '' make the 2 column font.color to Red
        rSheet.Resize(rSheet.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1).Font.Color = vbRed

        ''now clean up. Always set ranges to nothing when done with them.
        Set rSheet = Nothing
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! I understood the currentRegion property. It's quite useful since most of my fields are connected. 

But why do you set `rSheet = nothing`? Is it to cancel out all the selection?

Comment: Yes, It clears the rSheet from memory thus from future (accidental) use when you no longer require it. In your example, I'm clearing the rSheet from Sheet1 before i move to Sheet2. 
Its good practice to clear memory when you no longer need that object.