# Renaming a Range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this has been done to death but I can't quite figure out what is wrong with my code which is now throwing an "Application Defined or Object" error but ONLY when I run it from a button on a different sheet to the one with the data I wish to rename.

If I run it whilst on the tab I wish to edit it works fine

```
Sub updateDataSheet()
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastColumn = (Sheets("Data").Cells(1, columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
    lastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveWorkbook.Names("myData").RefersTo = Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
end sub
```

I assume I need to add in some additional reference but can't see what I'd be missing as an absolute Excel VBA newbie!

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is your name [local](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2176154/11683)?

Comment: It's on the excel file that I have open if that's what you mean by local. If I run from sheet "Data" it works fine, but if I run from sheet "Buttons" on the same workbook it throws the error

Comment: You have the same issue with not qualifying the `Cells` calls with a worksheet object as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323053/excel-vba-range-object-error-in-looping-through-worksheet/28323314#28323314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you,

```
Sub updateDataSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As long
    Dim lastRow As long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    With ws
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
        rng.Name = "myData"
    End With
End Sub
```

Once you determine the range you can name it.